# Multiple index.html in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have simple spring boot application with two html inside my webapp.
[image]

In my controller i have written mapping like:

```
@Controller
public class HtmlController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/anotherIndex", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String anotherIndex() {
    return "anotherIndex";
}
}
```

Also i have properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

When i pass in browser localhost:8080/ - i get my index.html page
But when i pass localhost:8080/anotherIndex i have exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [/anotherIndex.html]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/anotherIndex.html] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:205) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:145) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You have multiple typos? Look at the actual path in the exception; it seems that you have Spring Security in place but aren't handling the login page correctly.

Comment: There is a typo in your URL (localhost:8080/anoterIndex) missed the h letter =)

Comment: Sorry, it's a dummy code.
I ask about situation at all :)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem its you are not using the folder structure defined for a web application in Spring Boot.

You should have

```
src
   main
       resources
                templates
                         index.html
                         anotherIndex.html
                         anotherFolder
                             index.html
                         ...
```

Then from your Controller use (You have it right)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/anotherIndex", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String anotherIndex() {
    return "anotherIndex";
}
```

Comment: Yeah i know about this approach. I do similar in another project, where suffix "/" and prefix "/index.html".

But is any another solution exist?
For example a.html and b.html have similar js and css and i don't wont to put their in another folders.

Comment: You can create a folder static at same level as templates, and inside the common css and js, then since your html templates make reference to those files