# I want to display different html in Spring Boot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, controller

I need to test different client against each other. for that i need to be able to open different html pages with spring boot.

i tried to do this:
[Multiple index.html in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072061/multiple-index-html-in-spring-boot)
but it does only return a string "thick_client" on the webpage.

[image]

my controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class ApiController {
@Autowired
private StockRepository stockRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {
    return "thick_client";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/anotherIndex", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String anotherIndex() {
    return "thin_client";
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

My Folder Structure looks like this:

[image: Folder Structure]

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try returning the string without the extension.
For e.g return "thin_client";

Comment: it does not work, it only returns the string "thick_client" to the webpage

Comment: How about keeping everything the same and instead of `@GetMapping` use `@RequestMapping`

Comment: Or with `@GetMapping` add `@ResponseBody` annotation as well.

Comment: same output, i edited my post...maybe you find something now

Comment: I don't think the properties that you have defined in your properties file are required. Try removing them as well. And also are you using any template engine like thymeleaf ?

Comment: i deleted the properties, and still the same output.
no i dont youse thymeleaf

Comment: Ok try this last. Instead of '@RestController' use '@Controller'. It should work

Comment: now there is a 404 page not found error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246934/discussion-between-judo-urgens-and-aman-agarwal).